# Modifying button padding shifts other elements down?

Tags: html, css, button, mouseevent, stylesheet

I have been trying to create a button in CSS that appears to look "pushed down" on `:active`, to do this, I added `2px` to `padding-top` and subtracted `2px` from `padding-bottom`. However, this seems to add a margin to other elements, though I cannot figure out why.

I'm sure the solution is a simple one to experienced CSS-users.

http://jsfiddle.net/hTTWq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `inline-block` on the buttons who's default alignment is 'baseline`.

Try changing this by adding this to your buttton CSS

```
vertical-align: top; /* or middle or bottom */
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hTTWq/1/)

Comment: then when changing the padding-top and padding-bottom, the baseline is changed accordingly and that's why the other button is shifted. while the `vertical-align:top` or `vertical-align:middle` won't be changed by adjusting the padding (only changed by adjusting the `height`).

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, but to move the whole button (and not just the text), you could do something like this, which alters margin-top rather than padding:

```
*:active, *:focus {
    outline: none;
}
button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #a9a9a9;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: padding-top 100ms linear, padding-bottom 100ms linear, box-shadow 100ms linear, -webkit-filter 100ms linear;
    vertical-align: top;
}
button.suggested {
    background-color: #0074d9;
}
button:active {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5);
    margin-top: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```